Nextcloud Talk Failed to establish signaling connection. Retrying error only appears on chrome browser
After migrating from the old to the new signaling server, I'm experiencing an issue with Talk when I try to use it i get the "Failed to establish signaling connection. Retrying..." error on Chrome browser but other browsers like Firefox or Edge work just fine.
ping and telnet from the nc server to signaling is successful.
I tried to delete the Browser Cache and Cookies, and reset Chrome Extensions.
I also tried to disable UFW firewalls on my NC and signaling servers
output for services status:enter image description here
 janus.service - Janus WebRTC gateway
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/janus.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-07-13 14:35:05 +04; 1h 59min ago
       Docs: https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/index.html
    Process: 2609 ExecStart=/usr/bin/janus --disable-colors --daemon --log-stdout (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2611 (janus)
      Tasks: 34 (limit: 18998)
     Memory: 8.6M (peak: 10.8M)
        CPU: 17.707s
     CGroup: /system.slice/janus.service
             └─2611 /usr/bin/janus --disable-colors --daemon --log-stdout

Jul 13 14:58:42 signaling2024 janus[2611]: [Sat Jul 13 14:58:42 2024] [WARN] [5024200445104679] Peer video fallback SSRC: 3531010713
Jul 13 14:58:43 signaling2024 janus[2611]: [Sat Jul 13 14:58:43 2024] [5024200445104679] The DTLS handshake has been completed
Jul 13 14:58:43 signaling2024 janus[2611]: [Sat Jul 13 14:58:43 2024] [janus.plugin.videoroom-0x722fa4001d90] WebRTC media is now available
Jul 13 14:58:43 signaling2024 janus[2611]: [Sat Jul 13 14:58:43 2024] [ERR] [ice.c:janus_ice_outgoing_traffic_handle:4553] [5024200445104679] No candidates not gathered yet for stream??
Jul 13 14:58:44 signaling2024 janus[2611]: [Sat Jul 13 14:58:44 2024] [WARN] [5024200445104679] Unknown SSRC, dropping packet (SSRC 2210285321)...
Jul 13 14:58:46 signaling2024 janus[2611]: [Sat Jul 13 14:58:46 2024] [janus.plugin.videoroom-0x722fa4001d90] Data channel available
Jul 13 14:58:50 signaling2024 janus[2611]: [Sat Jul 13 14:58:50 2024] [janus.plugin.videoroom-0x722fa4001d90] No WebRTC media anymore; 0x72302c006b30 0x72302c004170
Jul 13 14:58:50 signaling2024 janus[2611]: [Sat Jul 13 14:58:50 2024] Detaching handle from JANUS VideoRoom plugin; 0x72302c006b30 0x722fa4001d90 0x72302c006b30 0x72302c004170
Jul 13 14:58:50 signaling2024 janus[2611]: [Sat Jul 13 14:58:50 2024] [5024200445104679] WebRTC resources freed; 0x72302c006b30 0x628e6ca69390
Jul 13 14:58:50 signaling2024 janus[2611]: [Sat Jul 13 14:58:50 2024] [5024200445104679] Handle and related resources freed; 0x72302c006b30 0x628e6ca69390


 coturn.service - coTURN STUN/TURN Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/coturn.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-07-13 14:15:20 +04; 2h 21min ago
       Docs: man:coturn(1)
             man:turnadmin(1)
             man:turnserver(1)
   Main PID: 1155 (turnserver)
      Tasks: 195 (limit: 18998)
     Memory: 64.0M (peak: 65.0M)
        CPU: 17.229s
     CGroup: /system.slice/coturn.service
             └─1155 /usr/bin/turnserver -c /etc/turnserver.conf --pidfile=

Jul 13 14:15:20 signaling2024 turnserver[1155]: 0: : IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
Jul 13 14:15:20 signaling2024 turnserver[1155]: 0: : IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
Jul 13 14:15:20 signaling2024 turnserver[1155]: 0: : IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
Jul 13 14:15:20 signaling2024 turnserver[1155]: 0: : IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
Jul 13 14:15:20 signaling2024 turnserver[1155]: 0: : IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
Jul 13 14:15:20 signaling2024 turnserver[1155]: 0: : IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
Jul 13 14:15:20 signaling2024 turnserver[1155]: 0: : IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
Jul 13 14:15:20 signaling2024 turnserver[1155]: 0: : IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
Jul 13 14:15:20 signaling2024 turnserver[1155]: 0: : IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
Jul 13 14:15:20 signaling2024 systemd[1]: Started coturn.service - coTURN STUN/TURN Server.


signaling.service - Nextcloud Talk signaling server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/signaling.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-07-13 14:15:20 +04; 2h 21min ago
   Main PID: 1881 (signaling)
      Tasks: 16 (limit: 18998)
     Memory: 29.7M (peak: 33.2M)
        CPU: 2.116s
     CGroup: /system.slice/signaling.service
             └─1881 /usr/bin/signaling --config /etc/signaling/server.conf

Jul 13 15:00:42 signaling2024 signaling[1881]: client.go:353: Client 8mw6HFRh3geAN-h2pvh23VHsizfy__d3dE116KDskkJ8VTRzNVRZT2hvX0RZTmlxZEtTdVZJLUUzUEozbXB4YUVfRTBPb0t2b0s2ek5ucFk0N0wwdkNPc2p>
Jul 13 15:01:36 signaling2024 signaling[1881]: client.go:353: Client 8mw6HFRh3geAN-h2pvh23VHsizfy__d3dE116KDskkJ8VTRzNVRZT2hvX0RZTmlxZEtTdVZJLUUzUEozbXB4YUVfRTBPb0t2b0s2ek5ucFk0N0wwdkNPc2p>
Jul 13 15:02:30 signaling2024 signaling[1881]: client.go:353: Client 8mw6HFRh3geAN-h2pvh23VHsizfy__d3dE116KDskkJ8VTRzNVRZT2hvX0RZTmlxZEtTdVZJLUUzUEozbXB4YUVfRTBPb0t2b0s2ek5ucFk0N0wwdkNPc2p>
Jul 13 15:03:24 signaling2024 signaling[1881]: client.go:353: Client 8mw6HFRh3geAN-h2pvh23VHsizfy__d3dE116KDskkJ8VTRzNVRZT2hvX0RZTmlxZEtTdVZJLUUzUEozbXB4YUVfRTBPb0t2b0s2ek5ucFk0N0wwdkNPc2p>
Jul 13 15:04:18 signaling2024 signaling[1881]: client.go:353: Client 8mw6HFRh3geAN-h2pvh23VHsizfy__d3dE116KDskkJ8VTRzNVRZT2hvX0RZTmlxZEtTdVZJLUUzUEozbXB4YUVfRTBPb0t2b0s2ek5ucFk0N0wwdkNPc2p>
Jul 13 15:05:12 signaling2024 signaling[1881]: client.go:353: Client 8mw6HFRh3geAN-h2pvh23VHsizfy__d3dE116KDskkJ8VTRzNVRZT2hvX0RZTmlxZEtTdVZJLUUzUEozbXB4YUVfRTBPb0t2b0s2ek5ucFk0N0wwdkNPc2p>
Jul 13 15:06:06 signaling2024 signaling[1881]: client.go:353: Client 8mw6HFRh3geAN-h2pvh23VHsizfy__d3dE116KDskkJ8VTRzNVRZT2hvX0RZTmlxZEtTdVZJLUUzUEozbXB4YUVfRTBPb0t2b0s2ek5ucFk0N0wwdkNPc2p>
Jul 13 15:07:00 signaling2024 signaling[1881]: client.go:353: Client 8mw6HFRh3geAN-h2pvh23VHsizfy__d3dE116KDskkJ8VTRzNVRZT2hvX0RZTmlxZEtTdVZJLUUzUEozbXB4YUVfRTBPb0t2b0s2ek5ucFk0N0wwdkNPc2p>
Jul 13 15:07:42 signaling2024 signaling[1881]: hub.go:951: Unregister 8mw6HFRh3geAN-h2pvh23VHsizfy__d3dE116KDskkJ8VTRzNVRZT2hvX0RZTmlxZEtTdVZJLUUzUEozbXB4YUVfRTBPb0t2b0s2ek5ucFk0N0wwdkNPc2>
Jul 13 15:07:42 signaling2024 signaling[1881]: clientsession.go:511: Removed room session kWSDKNkYburIWOAeT09XZ4QenYWg+6guH+qDNWXYlTtXaSGYn6mpz/q724IvacWmlvDO9DypsuY502ga+go0WrsQvtK2OqikPj>



 nats-server.service - NATS messaging server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nats-server.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-07-13 14:15:21 +04; 2h 22min ago
       Docs: https://docs.nats.io/nats-server/
   Main PID: 1893 (nats-server)
      Tasks: 12 (limit: 18998)
     Memory: 17.8M (peak: 21.0M)
        CPU: 2.418s
     CGroup: /system.slice/nats-server.service
             └─1893 /usr/bin/nats-server --config /etc/nats/nats.conf

Jul 13 14:15:21 signaling2024 systemd[1]: Started nats-server.service - NATS messaging server.
Jul 13 14:15:21 signaling2024 nats-server[1893]: [1893] 2024/07/13 14:15:21.520477 [INF] Starting nats-server
Jul 13 14:15:21 signaling2024 nats-server[1893]: [1893] 2024/07/13 14:15:21.520607 [INF]   Version:  2.10.16
Jul 13 14:15:21 signaling2024 nats-server[1893]: [1893] 2024/07/13 14:15:21.520610 [INF]   Git:      [80e29794]
Jul 13 14:15:21 signaling2024 nats-server[1893]: [1893] 2024/07/13 14:15:21.520613 [INF]   Name:     NA3PHTZKL4RJQV7TTMNOHQCIC6PHM4C3S5UUPYGMIBELGAQSVVASXZF4
Jul 13 14:15:21 signaling2024 nats-server[1893]: [1893] 2024/07/13 14:15:21.520621 [INF]   ID:       NA3PHTZKL4RJQV7TTMNOHQCIC6PHM4C3S5UUPYGMIBELGAQSVVASXZF4
Jul 13 14:15:21 signaling2024 nats-server[1893]: [1893] 2024/07/13 14:15:21.520642 [INF] Using configuration file: /etc/nats/nats.conf
Jul 13 14:15:21 signaling2024 nats-server[1893]: [1893] 2024/07/13 14:15:21.521353 [INF] Listening for client connections on 127.0.0.1:4222
Jul 13 14:15:21 signaling2024 nats-server[1893]: [1893] 2024/07/13 14:15:21.521384 [INF] Server is ready


screenshot from the Chrome browser


I don't know if it is a good solution but disabling "Use secure DNS" in the Chrome browser's settings solved the issue. after that, everything worked just fine.
